# Using mkvmerge to Merge Subtitle Tracks

Tags: video, video-conversion, video-editing, subtitles, matroska

I am looking for a way to merge two MKV files, each with an embedded subtitle track, into one where the subtitle tracks merge properly and in order. Right now I get two separate subtitle tracks, and not one single one. I do NOT want to hardcode. I can extract the SRT files from both, but have no idea how to merge them together properly. I am on a mac running macOS Catalina, but have some terminal experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer:
I am assuming both videos have the same video resolution, video codec, audio codec, video framerate, and have the same amount of tracks (1 video, 1 audio, 1 srt subtitle). You will need to provide further details about these two videos you are joining. If they are not **exactly the same** in terms of that jargon I just mentioned, then this easy method won't work and you will need a more involved and harder process.

Instructions:
Use MKVToolNix, a mac version is available and free, these instructions are for windows so take it with a grain of Mac salt and Windows-to-Mac translation.

1. Drag the 1st video into the **Source files:** area
2. Drag the 2nd video into the same area
3. A window will pop-up asking how you want to treat the 2nd video, select **Append to an existing source file** this joins the file, select OK
4. At the bottom there is a destination directory, choose where you want to save the file
5. At the very bottom click the **Start Multiplexing** button
6. Done!

Comment: Thank you! Some did differ enough I had to extract an SRT file and burn it in with uniconverter. But thank you, it did work for many of them!